# When building forms in ReactNative what is better, Formik or React Hook Form?

Tags: forms, react-native, formik, react-hook-form

It seems the concensus is divided over whether it is better to use Formik or React Hook Form, and so I've ended up quite confused over which to choose myself. On the one hand React Hook Forms seems to be faster and more lightweight but Formik appears to be easier to develop.

So to the developers who have tested both of these form libraries, which is the better one when making a ReactNative app?

Comment: maybe this will be a useful reference: https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#ReactHookFormFormikorReduxForm

Comment: @Bill Thankyou, but for ReactNative specifically does all that still apply? For example, can you still use uncontrolled components?

Comment: take a look at this section: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#ReactNative

Answer (score 0):

I have used recently both libraries on a project, I think both of them work fine with React Native, the important things to consider when choosing a form library are:

- Number of stars on GitHub and weekly downloads on NPM
- Performance
- Development - Is it well maintained
- Customisation and extendibility
- Size of the library
- Open issues
- Updates - how often is it updated

If you would like to get more deep into this topic you can check out this blog post where the two libraries are compared in detail: https://www.framelessgrid.com/react-hook-form-vs-formik-react-form-library-comparison-in-2021/